# Horizontal Time Line that depend on the status picklist of an object in visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom Object (Candidate ) with the following

status picklist values

- Picklist1
- picklist2
- Piclklist3

I would like to create the horizontal Time line using visual force page  that would depend on the status of the picklist. This can be achieved by using the formula but i would like to have the banner using VF on the detail page of the record.

(EX: By default the status of the candidate would be "picklist1" and when the status is changed to "Picklist2" the image should move to that status on the time line.)[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using formula field which show image.

```
CASE(
    TEXT(StageName),
    'Stage 1', IMAGE("/resource/Stage_1_Image", "Stage1", 50, 600),
    'Stage 2', IMAGE("/resource/Stage_2_Image", "Stage2", 50, 600),
    'Stage 3', IMAGE("/resource/Stage_3_Image", "Stage3", 50, 600),
    ....
    ....
    'Stage X', IMAGE("/resource/Stage_X_Image", "StageX", 50, 600),
    IMAGE("/resource/Default_Image", "Deafault", 50, 600)
)
```

Please take a look at this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72766/how-to-create-a-visual-indicator-of-stage-on-opportunity-record) for further details.

Edit:

I added the following two images in static resource and created a formula field with the following formula.

[image]

[image]

```
CASE( 
TEXT(StageName), 
'Prospecting', IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrH6Z.png", "Prospecting", 50, 600), 
'Closed Won', IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rvJ5.png", "Closed Won", 50, 600), 
IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rvJ5.png", "Closed Won", 50, 600) 
)
```

Added this formula field in a new section at top with single column and here is the result for two different opportunities

[image]

[image]

The images should be modified to fit your requirement.